# Infinite, finitely generated linear group has indices of subgroups divisible by infinitely many primes

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be an infinite finitely generated group and suppose that $G$ is linear, i.e., that $G \leq \operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ for some field $K$.

Are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p$ divides $[G:N]$ for some normal subgroup $N < G$ of finite index?

I think this is true at least if $\operatorname{char} K = 0$, by Theorem 10.4 in the book "Infinite Linear Groups" by Wehrfritz.

EDIT: To clarify, let me rephrase the question. Let $\mathscr{N}$ be the set of all normal subgroups of $G$ with finite index. Is the following set of primes infinite? $$\pi = \{p \in \mathbb{Z}: p \text{ is a prime, and } p \mid [G:N] \text{ for some } N \in \mathscr{N} \}$$

Comment: @DerekHolt: No, since in that case for any prime $p$ you can find a normal subgroup with $G/N$ cyclic of order $p$.

Comment: I think the formulation is awkward in understanding how quantifies should be placed. I presume $N$ will depend on $p$, I.e. for each prime there is an $N$?

Comment: @ahulpke: Yes, that's right. Sorry about the confusion, I'll edit in to clarify.